# Matching string indexes

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

If I have the strings

```
s1 = "PHONE" 
s2 = "EHNOP" # this is just s1 that has been alphabetically sorted
```

How can I determine which **indexes** of `s2` need to change to make it equivalent to `s1`? By this I mean, `s2[0]` should be `s2[4]` and `s[3]` should be `s[2]` etc.

I don't want to actually sort `s2` I just need to know the indexes in which `s2`'s letters should be, to match `s1`

Comment: Where is your code, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: My question is an extremely simplified version of my problem, my actual code is around 50 lines and involves sorting lists depending on a string. It would be no help to post it.

Comment: Then cut it down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your requirements are also vague. What does change mean? Are the strings always going to have the same letters?

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = "PHONE"
s2 = "EHNOP"
st = set()

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for ind, s in enumerate(s1):
    d[s].append(ind)

for ind, s in enumerate(s2):
    s_ind = d[s].pop(0)
    if s_ind != ind and (ind, s_ind) not in st:
        st.add((s_ind, ind))
print(st)
set([(3, 2), (4, 0)])


s2 = list(s2)

for a, b in st:
    s2[b],s2[a] = s2[a],s2[b]
print("".join(s2))
PHONE
```

If you have repeated letters and want to rejoin you will have to do some extra work but the code above will find the indexes to swap and find the indexes with  repeated letters also: